# Automatic WordPress Plugin Updates for only one specific plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I was wondering if the new filter for automatic updates (since WordPress 3.7) can be modified to only target one or more specific plugins?

This is the original filter in the WordPress Codex:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!!!

Regards,

Jan

Answer (score 1):

This code should exclude certain plugins for being updated automatically.

```
function exclude_plugins_from_auto_update ( $update, $item ) {
    $plugins = array ( // Plugins to exclude from auto-update
        'akismet',
        'buddypress',
    );
    if ( in_array( $item->slug, $plugins ) )
        return false; // Don't auto-update specified plugins
    else return true; // Auto-update all other plugins
}
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', 'exclude_plugins_from_auto_update', 10, 2 );
```

so modifying it to:

```
function plugins_to_auto_update ( $update, $item ) {
    $plugins = array ( // Plugins to  auto-update
        'akismet',
        'buddypress',
    );
    if ( in_array( $item->slug, $plugins ) )
        return true; // Auto-update specified plugins
    else return false; // Don't auto-update all other plugins
}
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', 'plugins_to_auto_update', 10, 2 );
```

should only update the plugins specified.

I haven't been able to test either of the above because I don't have any plugins that require updating, but the code in the first example is found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131404) and should work.